# Zebra-like css styling for nested DIVs

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have nested DIV elements, for which I don't know the levels of nesting. I need each to have different background than its parent creating a zebra-like colors. I am using only two backgrounds - dark and white. The effect needs to be similar to styling odd and even children in a container but in my case the children are nested. I can do this with rules for each nested element such as:

```
div  div  div  div {
    background-color: #fff;
}

div  div  div {
    background-color: #aaa;
}

div  div {
    background-color: #fff;
}

div {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

But I'm looking for more elegant solution.
Can this be done only with CSS? Do I need javascript?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Edit: I am looking for a solution which will not require the elements to have a class, since they will need to be rearranged with drag & drop (javascript)

Comment: Not a solution, but you could simplify the above css by grouping the elements: `div, div div div, div div div div div { ... }` and `div div, div div div div { ... }`.

Comment: AS for the actual solution, I'd just use javascript and even/odd classes since you are using javascript for the drag-and-drop anyway.

Comment: I'll probably go with that. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

*UPDATE: this solution is no longer relevant given the update to the question. Leaving it here for reference though.*

I would just use "even" and "odd" classes (or something equivalent):

```
div.even {
    background-color: #fff;
}

div.odd {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

And then in the HTML:

```
<div class="even">
    <div class="odd">
       <div class="even">
           <div class="odd">
               ...
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes i considered that but the elements also need to be rearranged by the user. I've edited my question. Thank you for your answer.