# Selector for even and odd level children

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the correct selector for selecting even and odd level children?

I would like to simplify my current CSS while allowing for infinite levels without manually writing in the CSS for them.

```
.box {
    max-width:100%;margin:25px 0px;padding: 15px;
    border:#d1ddbd solid  2px;
    background-color:#f3fae8;
}

.box > .box {
    border:#d1ddbd solid  1px;
    background-color:#fff;
}

.box > .box > .box {
    border:#d1ddbd solid  1px;
    background-color:#f3fae8;
}

.box > .box > .box > .box {
    border:#d1ddbd solid  1px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: There is no selector for odd/even 'levels' of descendants. If your back-end offers the capability to apply classes, or `data-*` attributes to the appropriate levels you could style using those instead, or, of course, JavaScript is an option, but there is no CSS-only solution for this.

Comment: @DavidThomas do you know if this is a proposed selector for the standard?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no. And given the potentially complex selectors (should a level be incremented every time a new descendant is found, or should it be only when a new descendant of a specified selector is found) I'm not sure it will or, practically, could be implemented. But, maybe in future.

Comment: Have you looked into [Less](http://lesscss.org/features/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide)? You should be able to write a recursive mixin that will compile to your desired CSS.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838961/zebra-like-css-styling-for-nested-divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with container queries now! just took 8 years.

basically, you use a container query to target a specific style, and inside of it you toggle the style itself:

```css
layering {
  container-name: layering;
  --depth-is-odd: true;
}

@container layering style(--depth-is-odd: true) {
  .layering {
   // styles for odd levels of nesting
    --depth-is-odd: false;
  }
}

@container layering style(--depth-is-odd: false) {
  .layering {
   // styles for even levels of nesting
    --depth-is-odd: true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Great first answer Igor! Sadly I left the project this CSS was used on last year so I won't be able to update it.

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to do this in CSS, other than just sitting down and writing the rules. It's not that big a deal to write ten rules, taking you down to ten nesting levels. Your alternative is to spend more time writing JS to add classes, or having your back-end add classes, or fighting with a SASS macro, any of which will take more time than this is worth.

```
.box {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin:    25px 0px;
  padding:   15px;
  border:    #d1ddbd solid 2px;
}

.box > .box {
  border-width: 1px;
}

.box,
.box > .box > .box, 
.box > .box > .box > .box > .box, 
.box > .box > .box > .box > .box > .box > .box,
.box > .box > .box > .box > .box > .box > .box > .box > .box {
    background-color:#f3fae8;
}

.box > .box, 
.box > .box > .box > .box, 
.box > .box > .box > .box > .box > .box,
.box > .box > .box > .box > .box > .box > .box > .box,
.box > .box > .box > .box > .box > .box > .box > .box, .box > .box {
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event you make "box" using div's you could do something like this. (See code and preview below)

```
div:nth-child(even)
{
    border:#d1ddbd solid  1px;
    background-color:#f3fae8;
    width:76px;
    height:75px;
}
div:nth-child(odd)
{
    border:#d1ddbd solid  1px;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:76px;
    height:75px;
}
#MainDiv{
    max-width:100%;margin:25px 0px;padding: 15px;
    border:#d1ddbd solid  2px;
    background-color:#f3fae8;
    display:block;
    padding:2px;
    height:auto;
}

    <div id="MainDiv">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

[image: Preview code output]

Comment: I don't believe this is the question being asked.

Comment: Well the question needs to have more detail cause otherwise they are looking at an element with the same class as the child inside that element. Maybe and example where this would be applied might help understand a different way to achieve a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set classes by JavaScript.

Depends on planed amount and appropriate performance. (I presume you don't need thousands.)

This example takes: 500 8ms, 5.5K 47ms, 55K 446ms

```
/** Extending Javascript Array for function Contains */
Array.prototype.contains = function (element) {
    return this.indexOf(element) > -1;
};

/** Set class "odd" to itself and run proceedEven() on all children with class "box" */
function proceedOdd(oddItem) {
    oddItem.classList.add("odd");
    if (oddItem.children.length) {
        [].forEach.call(oddItem.children, function (child) {
            if (child.classList.contains("box")) {
                proceedEven(child);
            }
        })
    }
}

/** Set class "even" to itself and run proceedOdd() on all children with class "box" */
function proceedEven(evenItem) {
    evenItem.classList.add("even");
    if (evenItem.children.length)
        [].forEach.call(evenItem.children, function (child) {
            if (child.classList.contains("box")) {
                proceedOdd(child);
            }
        })
}

// set root having first even box as child
var root = document.querySelectorAll("body");

if (root.length) {
    // just for case more in root
    [].forEach.call(root, function (rootItem) {
        if (rootItem.children.length)
            [].forEach.call(rootItem.children, function (child) {
                // proceed first level of evens - rest done recursively
                if (child.classList.contains("box")) proceedEven(child);
            });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a bit of JS would be the easiest way to simplify the CSS, unless you wanna use  LESS/SASS. - As already written above, there is no real way of doing this with short CSS selectors.

```js
(function addClasses(element, selector, level){
  [].forEach.call(element.querySelectorAll(selector), 
                  function (item, index) {
        item.className += " " + (level % 2 ? "white-bg" : "green-bg");
                    item.innerHTML += "";
                    addClasses(item, ".box", level+1);
                  }
  );
})(document, ".box", 0);
```

```css
.box {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin:25px 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: #d1ddbd solid  2px;
}

.box.white-bg {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: #d1ddbd solid  1px;
}
.box.green-bg {
  background-color: #f3fae8;
  border: #d1ddbd solid  1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  1
  <div class="box">1.1</div>
  <div class="box">1.2</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  2
  <div class="box">
    2.1
    <div class="box">
      2.1.1
      <div class="box">2.1.1.1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">2.1.2</div>
    <div class="box">2.1.3</div>
    <div class="box">2.1.4</div>
    <div class="box">2.1.5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    2.2
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    2.3
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  3
  <div class="box">3.1</div>
</div>
```